# Accessing Google 3D Maps Elevation Data

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, elevation, google-earth-engine, google-elevation-api

When we use google maps in 3D at Google earth, it shows building heights and structures' actual heights in elevation data. However, the google elevation API provided by google results only ground elevations and not the actual elevations of buildings on ground.

I tried **scraping** this data from google earth's web portal, but they transfer packets between server and browser highly encrypted, and that failed.

Can you please suggest any way to find this elevation data I am looking for?

Comment: I am also looking for the same information. I am trying to figure out if there's a way we can extract this info from Google Earth API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is currently not available in Google Maps Elevation API, the Elevation API currently supports the ground elevation but not the establishments. However, you may file a Feature Request in the [Google Maps Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and share your use case there in order for the engineers to review the feasibilty of your request.